# Access protected folder

Tags: c#

I have a list of the folders located in a certain partition .

I get the list of the folders in a treeview control but when I click a certain folder from the treeview , it must show me the folders/files of the selected folder in a listview but if the selected folder is protected I get "access is denied" .

I'm using `Directory.GetFolders` to get them.

Is there any way to bypass this?

Comment: If the folder is defined to **not** allow access to you - **no**, there is no way to "bypass" that .... that's the **whole point** of having folder permissions ...

Comment: What type of application do you create?

Comment: Run the application with higher privileges, so you have enough rights to access the folder in question.

Comment: Directory.GetDirectories(); not Directory.GetFolders();